# How to post Custom Header AWS pinpoint Email in NodeJs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I am forwarding Json to Lambda which eventually calls

```
pinpoint.sendMessages(params, function(err, data){}
```

Is there any way in Pinpoint can send custom header like an `emailID` in the Header information.

[Send Email by Using the Amazon Pinpoint API (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-messages-sdk.html#w273aac25b9c13b5b5)

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify custom email headers using the SendMessages operation in the Amazon Pinpoint API.

However, the sender identities that you've already configured in Pinpoint are also available in Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES). You can use [the SendRawEmail operation in the Amazon SES API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendRawEmail.html) to create your own message with any custom headers that you want to add.

You can also use [the SES SMTP interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html) to send email through existing mail clients or other applications. Many of these apps let you specify your own headers.

The Amazon SES documentation also contains ready-to-use code examples that you can use to [send raw email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-raw-using-sdk), or [send email using the SMTP interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-using-smtp).

I hope this helps!

Brent @ AWS